# Unable to get SessionRepository while integrating Spring Session using JDBC with Grails3

Tags: postgresql, spring-session, grails-3.3.x

I am unable to integrate `Spring Session` with `Grails-3.3.15` application using `JDBC` to persist `HttpSession` in `PostgreSQL` db. I get `BeanCreationException` upon startup of the application.

## Background:

I referred to [official guide here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/2.1.5.RELEASE/reference/html5/guides/grails3.html) explained for Redis implementation (Could not find relevant guide for JDBC) and did below mentioned changes to implement for JDBC:

1. build.gradle:

```
compile "org.springframework.session:spring-session-jdbc"
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
```

2. application.groovy:

```
spring.datasource.url=System.getenv("DB_URL")
spring.datasource.username=System.getenv("DB_USERNAME")
spring.datasource.password=System.getenv("DB_PASSWORD")
```

3. application.yml

```
spring:
  session:
    store-type: "jdbc"
    table-name: "SPRING_SESSION"
```

## Problem:

Here is the stacktrace of the exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.session.SessionAutoConfiguration$SessionRepositoryValidator': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No session repository could be auto-configured, check your configuration (session store type is 'jdbc')
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1622)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:756)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:666)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:353)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:300)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:84)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:393)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:380)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:136)
    at com.foo.bar.Application.main(Application.groovy:8)
```

## Troubleshooting:

Upon further debugging, I found that in `checkSessionRepository()` of `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.session.SessionRepositoryValidator` `sessionRepositoryProvider.getIfAvailable()` is returning `null` and the method throws `IllegalArgumentException`.

It seems that `SessionRepository` is not getting configured.
Is there anything that I am missing?
Any help will be appreciated.